# Is there a way to integrate chatbot created using IBM Watson with Skype?

Tags: ibm-watson, chatbot, watson-conversation, skypedeveloper

I want to make a chatbot using IBM Watson for Skype. I am not getting any tutorial to integrate it with Skype. I am confused with various tools and platforms like botkit, chatfuel, IBM Conversation Middleware etc. Anyone can show light on it?

Answer (score 3):

Watson Conversation is one REST API endpoint, so you can build some Skype app for call the Watson endpoint with code.

You can use botkit-framework, have support with Microsoft Bot Framework, including Skype, but you would have to adjust for the new botkit additions by writing some of your own custom code.

Obs.: Try to talk with Skype people professionals to see how to connect one bot API, in this case, Watson Conversation Service.

Reference: [Mitch Mason](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/watson/2016/11/new-botkit-integration-makes-deploying-watson-bots-messaging-apps-easy/)

Comment: Thank You @Sayuri Mizuguchi

Comment: If this answer follows the [Stackoverflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), please mark the question and help other's that have the same doubt.